# Where to find medium-sized open source C (also C++) programs with multiple source files (> 15)

Tags: c++, c

A rather specific question, but I am looking for medium-sized C/C++ programs that I can use to benchmark my application. I understand that there are tools / benchmarking tools but I have my own benchmarking tool but I need more tests medium-sized tests.

Comment: What application?  A compiler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GitHub has many open source projects with many files. Just search `C` (or `C++`) as the language and [thousands of open source projects will appear.](https://github.com/search?l=C&q=c&ref=cmdform&type=Repositories)

Comment: Hmm, yes how dumb of me........